# How I can order data pre date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how I can do order data from `API` pre-date very time.

How its should be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>2017-02-17</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some date</td>
        <td>some date</td>
        <td>some date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>2017-02-15</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some date</td>
        <td>some date</td>
        <td>some date</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

example:

`URL API`: http://api.tradingeconomics.com/calendar?c=guest:guest

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "Get",
    datatype: "JSON",
    contentType: "application/json",
    error : function (data) { console.log("error:" + data) },
    success: function (response) {
        response.forEach(function (data) {

            $('.top_table').append(
                "<tr>" +
                    "<th>DATE</th>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr id='content'>" +
                    "<td>some text....</td>" +
                    "<td>some text....</td>" +
                    "<td>some text....</td>" +
                    "<td>some text....</td>" +
                "</tr>"
            );

        });

        console.log(response);

    }

});
```

But its print like:

> date
>   result
>   date
>   result

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I've understood your question very well, but I think that could give you some tips.

Your `API` returns an `Array` of `Objects` if you make and `Ajax` `GET` request, so you can order this `Array` before inserting the content into the `DOM`:

> The next example order the data in descending order comparing the `Date` parameter, there is another date parameter called `LastUpdate`, I don't know if you want to use it in your logic.

```
$.get("https://api.tradingeconomics.com/calendar?c=guest:guest", function (data) {

    //---Order the array received from the server
    data.sort(function (a, b) {

        return (new Date(a.Date)) - (new Date(b.Date));

    });

    //---The data is ordered, you can insert it into the DOM

});
```

In the other hand, your code inserts a row with the `header` content and a row with the `body` content in each iteration, this is not correct. You need to add all the header texts in a single row and each item of the `Array` needs to be inserted in separated rows.

Here you have a working example to give you an idea of the process:

https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/ym8qp415/

**EDIT:** Seeing your comments, I understand now that you want to **grouping** the data not just **ordering** it. I recommend you to use the `reduce` method of the `Array` class to create a new data separated by dates and after that you can insert the data in the table:

```
var regdate = /^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$/;

//---Sort the data from the server
data.sort(function (a, b) {

    return (new Date(a.Date)) - (new Date(b.Date));

});

var group = data.reduce(function (before, current) {

    var day = current.Date.replace(regdate, "$1");
    var hour = current.Date.replace(regdate, "$2");

    if (!before[day]) {

        before[day] = [];

    }

    current.Hour = hour;

    before[day].push(current);

    return before;

}, {});

//---The data is ordered and grouped, you can insert it into the DOM
```

Working example with fake data (Because of the example in the API returns only one day):

http://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/nvv4fnon/

Comment: yes this is what i need but its possible to order it like this: http://www.tradingeconomics.com/calendar

Comment: @idantraders, look at my last edit, you need to **group** the data received from the API, no just **order** them.

Comment: thank you very much. only one question how i can control the data? if i not need everything? how i can choose?

Comment: @idantraders, instead of inserting all the data, just use to the parameters that you need. e.g: `row.Date`, `row.Event`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Without a plugin, this is going to be difficult to achieve unless the "calendar" information is pulled from a database, it may be worth sorting in PHP, loading and displaying the data in jQuery

```
<script type="javascript">
$(function() {
    $("BODY").on("click", "TH[data-orderby]", function() {
        var order = $(this).data("orderby") || "date";
        var parent = $(this).parents("table").parent();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'calendar?c=guest:guest',
            data: 'order-by=' + URLEncode(order),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                parent.html(response);
            },
            error: function(event, request, settings) {
                console.warn("Ajax Error", request);
            }
        })
    });
});
</script>
<div class="parent">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading</th>
        <th data-orderby="date">Date</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th data-orderby="last_updated">Last Updated</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Because we use `$("BODY").on("click", "TH[data-orderby]")`, even when the data is reloaded from the server, the sort functionality will remain.

I hope this helps.

Comment: what i mean i would like to order the data like here:
http://www.tradingeconomics.com/calendar

from the API url to the table, i can do it in server side but i would like to know if i have some way to do it in jquery

Comment: There are many jquery table sorting plugins about, see https://plugins.jquery.com/tablesorter/

Comment: i need it like the example in the url.. do you know maybe plugin do it like i give you in the link? and its not need to be a table it can be css and <div>